# Linear equation having n variables

Tags: linear-algebra

In a group of n persons, each person is asked to write down the sum of the
ages of all the other $n − 1$ persons. Suppose the sums so obtained are
$s_1, \ldots , s_n$. It is now desired to find the actual ages of the persons from these
values.

(a) Formulate the problem in the form of a system of linear equations.

(b) Can the ages be always uniquely determined? Justify your answer.

My progress

Each person's age will be added $n-1$ times i.e $$(n-1)(a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots +a_n)=s_1+s_2+s_3+\ldots +s_n.$$From this I can say that when I divide  sum obtained $s_1+s_2+ \ldots +s_n$ by $n-1$,this will end up in a linear equation with $n$ variables.
I don't know if we can uniquely determined their ages as there are $n$ variables and just one equation.According to me,its not possible

Note:I do not have its solution or its answers so I cannot verify myself if I am correct or not.

Comment: "According to me, its not possible": because you only considered one equation. But there are many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to the solution:

$$s:=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots s_n}{n-1}$$ indeed gives you the sum of the ages.

Then

$$s-s_k=a_k$$ for any $k$ !

---

You can write the system as follows

$$\begin{cases}s_1=a_1+a_2+\cdots a_n-a_1,\\s_2=a_1+a_2+\cdots a_n-a_2,\\\cdots\\s_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots a_n-a_n.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I didn't consider that ai person summed all the ages except his age and subtracting what he has summed up from summation of ages will give ai person's age.I should have given some more time to the problem.while solving a problem its always about giving time and understanding the problem what it says.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The system of equations would looks as follows:
$$\begin{cases}a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n=s_1\\a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n=s_2\\\qquad\qquad~~~~\vdots\\a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-2}+a_n=s_{n-1}\\a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}=s_n\end{cases}$$
where $s_i$ are the sums of the ages of the other $n-1$ people, from the perspective of the $i-$th person, and $a_i$ is the age of the $i-$th person. The coefficient matrix is then:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&\cdots&1&1\\1&0&1&\cdots&1&1\\1&1&0&\cdots&1&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\1&1&1&\cdots&0&1\\1&1&1&\cdots&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix has determinant $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$, so if $n>1$ then this matrix is invertible. So if $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ are given, then there is always a unique solution for the individual ages, $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_i$ be the age of person $i$, so that $s_i = \sum_{k\ne i} a_i$.
Moreover, let $S$ be the sum of ages across all people.

The initial linear system has $n$ equations:
$$s_i = a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{i-1} + a_{i+1} + \ldots + a_n \qquad \mbox{for } i=1, 2, \ldots, n$$
Adding them all, you get
$$(n-1) S = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i$$
so that
$$S =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n s_i}{n-1}$$

Having computed $S$, note that $s_i = S - a_i$ and rewrite the $i$-th equation as
$$s_i = S - a_i$$
to obtain $a_i = S - s_i$, for each $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$. This gives you a unique solution for $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ given $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n$.

Comment: Thanks for clear solution but i saw Yves's solution first and accepted it.